# Search Object Array for string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to search for a string contained in an object array.

```
image_array = [
            {image: '/assets/monkey-face.jpg', link_url: '/animal/showit?animal=Monkey'},
            {image: '/assets/tiger-face.jpg', link_url: '/animal/showit?animal=Tiger'} 

]
```

Will not find the string 'monkey' or 'tiger' in the url parameter showit or the image.

```
    image_array.IndexOf 
jQuery.inArray
```

If I try to loop through the array/object and search for the string I get:

```
"Object #<Object> has no method 'search'"
```

Where am I going wrong - why does it return -1 when the object has the string in it?

Comment: Have you tried the `src` attribute of your image?

Comment: Well, error seems clear. Your array contains objects not strings, and objects don't have a method `search`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < image_array.length; i++){
  if(image_array[i].link_url.indexof("Monkey") != -1){
    // Item found
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array does not have search method - it is for string. Try [$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
var result = $.grep(image_array, function(item){
    return item.link_url.indexOf('Monkey') >= 0;
})

//result will be an array with all items having `Monkey` in link_url
console.log(result)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7RnME/)

Comment: Thanks Arun. I needed the index of the object in the array so the accepted answer worked best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to check whether a string is contained inside the object values, assuming the string is not used as any key values, try the following:

```
 return JSON.stringify(image_array).indexOf("monkey") > 0
```

Hope this helps :)